# Explicitly retrieving contents of XML element as string

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have XML like this:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <fullstoryimage>
        <img src="http://someimageurl/animage.jpg" width="220" height="150" border="0" />
    </fullstoryimage>
</entry>
```

and a model like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("entry", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class NewsItem
{
    [XmlElement("fullstoryimage")]
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

How do I appropriately tag 'fullstoryimage' to pull the contents as a string?

Note: The XML is not of my design and cannot change, however silly it may look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an effort of keeping my serialization consistent, I went with this:

```
public class StoryImage
{
    [XmlElement("img")]
    public Image Img { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    [XmlAttribute("src")]
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("entry", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class NewsItem
{
    [XmlElement("fullstoryimage")]
    public StoryImage FullStoryImage { get; set; }
}
```

The URL is then accessible by newsItem.FullStoryImage.Img.Source.

Answer (score 0):

If what your are trying to do is getting the image link, you can use Linq2Xml

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var imgLink = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                .Descendants(ns + "img")
                .Select(i => i.Attribute("src").Value)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ideally I'd like something that uses tagging and a deserializer to go directly to a model. I simplified it a lot in the example above, but I have a lot of other properties that are populated that way and for consistency's sake I'd like 'fullstoryimage' to be as well. If it proves impossible I will use your approach though, thank you.